# String matching alternate approach

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, string-matching

Trying to write my own fast pattern matching algo. Dont want to use language specific solution. I am focussing on writing the algo. This is because I was reading about different techniques to do string matching. Some are complicate yet very interesting like Rabin karp, etc.
I came up with this method which is fast and linear. It works well with the different inputs I have tried with. So I was thinking is there any reason I shouldnt be using this approach over the very well know approaches. Basically I am taking a char of text and comparing with the corresponding character of the pattern - one at a time. 
Also, if someone could point out my mistake in this one - it will be great. Thank you for your replies and comments in advance :)

```
public static boolean patternMatch(String pattern, String text)
{
    if(pattern == null)
        return true;
    if(text == null)
        return false;

    char[] patternArray = pattern.toCharArray();
    char[] textArray = text.toCharArray();

    int length = pattern.length();
    int j = 0;
    for(char t : textArray)
    {
        if(t == patternArray[j])
        {
            j++;
            if(j == length)
                return true;
        }
        else {
            j = 0; 
            if(t == patternArray[j]) j++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What are the requirements of the method? You haven't posted that so it's impossible to say whether it is good or bad. Can you show some examples of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Control question: What if the text contains repeating sequences, like "xyxyz" and matching it against "xyz", does your method do what you want then?

Comment: Does your programming language or runtime contain string methods like IndexOf or Contains? If so, why are you not using them?

Comment: How is this different than a naive string matching algorithm?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : Its a usual string pattern matching algorithm, that I have created. Just wanted to come up with something simple and fast. 
Good point about xyz - I updated it in else to cover that scenario. What do you think. It works for that case in particular too.

Comment: @JoelCornett the naive as in brute force ones? They take O(n^2) time, this one doesnt.

Comment: How about match 'xxxy' with 'xxxxy'? As Ted Hoop point out in his answer, I believe your algo is wrong :)

Comment: Sigh, I get it. Thanks for the nice points all of you. I guess that's why the finite state solution and the hashing solution are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons for using a standard approach:

1. It's easy to write a method that simply does the wrong thing. Your method is like that, because it will fail to match, for instance, the pattern "ab" against the string "aab". (It matches the first "a"s of the pattern and the string, then fails to match "b" to the second "a" of the string, then goes on to see if it can find a match starting at the third character of the string.)
2. Standard approaches are *fast*. Your algorithm is linear, which is pretty good (if only it were also correct!). However, many string matching algorithms will work in *sublinear* time. That is, the time it takes to match a string grows more slowly than linearly in the size of the input problem. Perhaps hard to believe, but true. (Read the literature for substantiations of this claim.)